# How do I list all value= options in an html (aspx) page

Tags: html, asp.net

I am working off a .NET website that has a bunch of webforms.  The user types in their data via a browser and the submitted data is pushed a SQL Server database.

I am trying to analyze the data in the database but am struggling because there is no code book which shows me what the codes 1, 2, 3 etc represent.

Is there some relatively simple tool in Javascript or something that I can use to extract all the options in the dropdown list and tell me how they are coded ?  For instance, by right-clicking on the source code I can see that for `Mode:` there are three options:  `1=Research, 2=Test and 3=Non-Research`.

I've got a couple of hundred of these things so I do not really want to do this by hand...

I am thinking there are some tools (hopefully online, maybe JSFiddle) that can do this automatically.

I have copied a snippet of the HTML below.  I do not know if it helps but the page uses:

- bootstrap.js
- jquery.js
- some CSS

  ```
              <tr>
                  <th class="newpatient-label">Mode:
                  </th>
                  <td>
                      <select name="ctl00$cphBody$fvPatient$modeDropDownList" id="cphBody_fvPatient_modeDropDownList">
                          <option selected="selected" value="1">Research</option>
                          <option value="3">Non-Research</option>
                          <option value="2">Test</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <th class="newpatient-label">Condition:</th>
                  <td>
                      <select name="ctl00$cphBody$fvPatient$ddlCondition" id="cphBody_fvPatient_ddlCondition">
                          <option value="1">Active</option>
                          <option selected="selected" value="2">Inactive</option>

                      </select>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <th class="newpatient-label">Alternate ID:
                  </th>
                  <td>
                      <input name="ctl00$cphBody$fvPatient$alternateIdTextBox" type="text" value="097175EM" id="cphBody_fvPatient_alternateIdTextBox" />
                      <span id="cphBody_fvPatient_rfvPatientCmsId" style="display:none;">*</span>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <th class="newpatient-label">Alias:</th>
                  <td>
                      <input name="ctl00$cphBody$fvPatient$aliasTextBox" type="text" value="4159714811" id="cphBody_fvPatient_aliasTextBox" />
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <th class="newpatient-label">Preferred Language:
                  </th>
                  <td colspan="1">
                      <select name="ctl00$cphBody$fvPatient$languageDropDown" id="cphBody_fvPatient_languageDropDown">
                          <option value="3">Amharic </option>
                          <option value="4">Arabic </option>
                          <option value="5">Brazilian Portuguese </option>
                          <option value="6">Burmese </option>
                          <option value="7">Chin </option>
                          <option value="8">Chuukese </option>
                          <option value="9">Dari </option>
                          <option selected="selected" value="1">English </option>
                          <option value="10">French </option>
                          <option value="11">German </option>
                          <option value="12">Greek </option>
                          <option value="13">Haitian </option>
                          <option value="14">Hindi </option>
                          <option value="15">Hmong </option>
                          <option value="16">Ilocano </option>
                          <option value="17">Indonesian </option>
                          <option value="18">Italian </option>
                          <option value="20">Japanese </option>
                          <option value="19">Jarai </option>
                          <option value="21">Karen </option>
                          <option value="22">Khmer </option>
                          <option value="23">Korean </option>
                          <option value="24">Kurdish </option>
                          <option value="25">Lao </option>
                          <option value="26">Malayalam </option>
                          <option value="27">Marshallese </option>
                          <option value="28">Nepali </option>
                          <option value="29">Oromo </option>
                          <option value="46">Other </option>
                          <option value="30">Persian </option>
                          <option value="31">Polish </option>
                          <option value="32">Punjabi </option>
                          <option value="33">Romanian </option>
                          <option value="34">Rundi </option>
                          <option value="35">Russian </option>
                          <option value="36">Serbian </option>
                          <option value="2">Spanish </option>
                          <option value="37">Swahili </option>
                          <option value="38">Swedish </option>
                          <option value="39">Tagalog </option>
                          <option value="40">Tamil </option>
                          <option value="41">Thai </option>
                          <option value="42">Tigrinya </option>
                          <option value="43">Traditional Chinese </option>
                          <option value="44">Urdu </option>
                          <option value="45">Vietnamese </option>

                      </select>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the HTML you can do it with jquery like this.

variable html contains the html you provided

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/jcastillo/pen/gpdGKm)

```
$(function() {
  var tmpHTML = $(html);
  var vals = [];

  //get all existing SELECT menus
  tmpHTML.find("select").each(function(index, itm) {
    var opts = [];

    //loop through each of the menu's options
    $(this).find("option").each(function(i, opt) {
      if (opt.text!== '') {
        opts.push({
          value: opt.value,
          text: opt.text
        });
      }
    });

    //push the menu along with its options into an array
    vals.push({
      id: itm.id,
      options: opts
    });
  });

  console.log(vals);
});
```

vals contains the list of menus along with their options

Comment: Hi Juan,  the code works for the HTML that you created but with all the double quotes in my HTML, the code will not work.  How would it escape all the double quotes?

Comment: i used a minifier for the html and placed the result inside of apostrophes https://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/