# How do I get all the options and labels of radio buttons using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

This is a follow up to my previous question about drop down menus:  [list options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550661/how-do-i-list-all-value-options-in-an-html-aspx-page)

I did not realize it previously but in addition to dropdowns there are several radio buttons where I'd like to get the text of the radio button, the values and labels.

```
var html = '<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2 class="table table-striped"><tr><td class=registration-form>Is the patient enrolled in a VDOT research protocol?*<td><span id=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100100 class="radio inline control-group" maintainscrollpositiononpostback=true><input id=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100100_0 type=radio name=ctl00$cphBody$surveyControll$surveyWizard$S0100100 value=1 checked><label for=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100100_0>Yes&nbsp</label><input id=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100100_1 type=radio name=ctl00$cphBody$surveyControll$surveyWizard$S0100100 value=0 onclick="setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$cphBody$surveyControll$surveyWizard$S0100100$1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)"><label for=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100100_1>No</label></span> <span id=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_rfvS0100100 class=text-error style=display:none>required</span><tr id=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_ShowS0100200><td class=registration-form>Informed Consent signed?*<td><span id=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100200 class="radio inline control-group"><input id=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100200_0 type=radio name=ctl00$cphBody$surveyControll$surveyWizard$S0100200 value=1 checked><label for=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100200_0>Yes &nbsp</label><input id=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100200_1 type=radio name=ctl00$cphBody$surveyControll$surveyWizard$S0100200 value="0"><label for=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100200_1>No</label></span> <span id=cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_rfvS0100200 class=text-error style=display:none>required</span></table>';

$(function () {
    var tmpHTML = $(html);
    var vals = [];
    //get all existing SELECT menus
    tmpHTML.find("select").each(function (index, itm) {
        var opts = [];

        //loop through each of the menu's options
        $(this).find(":radio").each(function (i, opt) {
            if (opt.text !== '') {
                opts.push({
                    value: opt.val,
                    text: opt.text
                });
            }
        });

        //push the menu along with its options into an array
        vals.push({
            id: itm.id,
            options: opts
        });
    });
    console.log(vals);
});
```

Changing the code here:  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/jcastillo/pen/gpdGKm) and inserting the HTML (below) as the the var `html` and also changing the two `finds` to `span` and `label` gave me arrays that are all undefined

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td class="registration-form">Is the patient enrolled in a VDOT research protocol?*</td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100100" class="radio inline control-group" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true">
                          <input id="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100100_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$cphBody$surveyControll$surveyWizard$S0100100" value="1" checked="checked" />
                          <label for="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100100_0">Yes&nbsp</label>
                          <input id="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100100_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$cphBody$surveyControll$surveyWizard$S0100100" value="0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$cphBody$surveyControll$surveyWizard$S0100100$1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" />
                          <label for="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100100_1">No</label></span>
                        <span id="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_rfvS0100100" class="text-error" style="display:none;">required</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_ShowS0100200">
                  <td class="registration-form">Informed Consent signed?*</td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100200" class="radio inline control-group">
                          <input id="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100200_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$cphBody$surveyControll$surveyWizard$S0100200" value="1" checked="checked" />
                          <label for="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100200_0">Yes &nbsp</label>
                          <input id="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100200_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$cphBody$surveyControll$surveyWizard$S0100200" value="0" />
                          <label for="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_S0100200_1">No</label></span>
                        <span id="cphBody_surveyControll_surveyWizard_rfvS0100200" class="text-error" style="display:none;">required</span>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not just as a codepen link.

Comment: You can use `tmpHTML.find(":radio")` to get all the radio buttons. `.val()` to get its value, and `.text()` to get the text.

Comment: I edited my post to include code.  I also added the ":radio" and changed value to val but all I got was the 0 and 1.

Comment: I don't see `:radio` in your code.

Comment: Why do you expect to get something other than 0 and 1? That's all you have in the HTML.

Comment: I did not paste that code block in..  I need the labels (Yes/No), the values (0/1) and the question 'Informed Consent signed?'  because some of the question have more than two radio button options

Comment: That first variable `var html = '....`has bad escaping in it.

Answer (score 0):

Given a radio button in `this`, you can get its value with `this.value` or `$(this).val()`. You can get the text of the associated label with:

```
$(this).closest("label").add($("label[for='" + this.id + "']")).text()
```

This shows how to get all of them in an array:

```
$(function () {
    var tmpHTML = $(html);
    var vals = [];
    //get all existing SELECT menus
    tmpHTML.find(":radio").each(function () {
        vals.push({
            value: this.value,
            text: $(this).closest("label").add($("label[for='" + this.id + "']")).text()
        });
    });
    console.log(vals);
});
```

Comment: where should this code snippet go in the code above?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to get them all. I don't understand why you were searching for radios inside the `"select"` loop, since radios aren't part of `<select>` elements.

Comment: Given my complete lack of understanding, I am totally lost here now.  I need to start a new question that is more clear.